# Necessary/Sufficiency Conditions for Measurable Mapping

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory

I'm interested in seeing if it is possible to have a numerical (implementable on a finite precision computer) method to determine if a given function is measurable or not. It would be great if some one could direct me towards some references to this end if it's a very well studied thing; I'm just finding it a little hard to search.

**An example application**: Say I have a complicated procedure that can be expressed as a mapping $f$, between two measurable spaces $(\Omega, F)$ and $(\Lambda,G)$, given that the measure in the first space is a probability measure ($\mu(\Omega)=1$). I am interested in assigning a probability for each subset $\lambda\in G$ based on it's pre-image in $f^{-1}(\lambda)\in F$. If $f$ is measurable, I can do this simply as
\begin{equation}
p(\lambda) = \mu(f^{-1}(\lambda)).
\end{equation}

- Key here is that it may not be possible to express the procedure as an analytic function and the best I can do is write a numerical code for it that generates $f(x), \frac{d}{dx}f(x), \dots $ for any given $x\in \Omega$.
- Also, $\Omega$ could be high-dimensional, potentially, so graphical approaches might not be feasible in the general sense.
- Having quick conditions to check for the measurability of $f$ could greatly aid in understanding the appropriateness of the above formula.

Edit: I'm editing this in response to the holds. I have removed the word "numerical" from the title, indicating that I'm looking for some practically useful result that I can use to determine if a given mapping is measurable or not. I understand that numerical implementation could be a separate question by itself. So all the question now seeks is **some useful result that could be in the form of necessary or sufficient conditions for measurability of a function**. I'm leaving the bode of the question intact to retain the context of this edit.

Comment: I struggle to see how this could be done. Even the far simpler problem of showing that the pre-image of open set is open when the function is continuous seems quite impossible to do numerically.

Comment: I would be curious to know why this question is attracting so many votes for closure and no constructive criticism?